# Form processing using GCDWebServer and Swift

Tags: swift, gcdwebserver

Wondering if anyone has gotten form processing working from Swift. Taking a cue from the form on the [README](https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer#advanced-example-2-implementing-forms) it says to return the following for the addHandlerForMethod (in Objective-C)...

```
return [GCDWebServerDataResponse responseWithHTML:html];
```

So I thought I could simply use the following from Swift...

```
return GCDWebServerDataResponse(HTML: html)
```

This causes a "Missing argument for parameter 'contentType' in call" error. Ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `GCDWebServerDataResponse.responseWithHTML(html)`?

Comment: That is what I tried first. Should have mentioned that. However, the responseWithHTML is a class method and Swift doesn't see the method.